# PDFsharp, meassure height of a string with a specific width

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

Rather new to C# and like Bambi on ice to PDFsharp. And it is my first post to this forum, so, please be patient!

I have created some order reports using PrintDocument and now I want to create PDFs.

With a wrapper class and extensions I only need to write one set of "layout code" that can use either PDFsharp or PrintDocument.

BUT, I don't know how to meassure the height of a string at a certain width, like the Graphics's SizeF MeasureString(string str, Font aFont, int width). As it is based on the Graphics, I must know the height without printing it.
I have been searching for an answer, but not getting the answers to put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp uses the `XGraphics` class for drawing. And `XGraphics` also has a `MeasureString` method.

And `XGraphics` can also be used for printing, so maybe you only need one implementation using PDFsharp's `XGraphics` class.

With PDFsharp's `XGraphics` class you can only get width and height for a specific text with a specific font height, so to get the height for a specific width this may require doing a loop (maybe with interval nesting) to determine the appropriate font height.

To determine the height of multi-line text you can use one class from the `XTextFormatterEx` family of classes. Maybe this is what you need.
See here:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3192

Comment: But not so I can get the height at a certain width. Oh, can I print directly to a printer? Thought it has to go via a pdf file...
Sorry if many edits, used enter for new line....

Comment: I admit I don't know what "SizeF MeasureString(string str, Font aFont, int width)" does, but I updated my answer. Is it for single-line text or for multi-line text?

Comment: It can be a single line or multi line, or a text that does not fit and has to be splitted into multiple lines. The returned SizeF from MeasureString(string str, Font aFont, int width) has the Height set to the messured height, and it works like sharm.

Comment: If it can be multi-line then XTextFormatterEx should be the way to go. And you can see XTextFormatterEx as a sample that can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: I have to take look at XTextFormatterEx then.
I think the  XGraphics.FromGraphics(...) will not "transfer" it as text, would be nice otherwise... Thank you Bally!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it with a neat extension method:

```
 public static XSize MeasureString(this XGraphics gfx, string txt, XFont font, double width)
    {
        int lastfitchar;
        double neededHeight;
        XTextFormatterEx tf = new XTextFormatterEx(gfx);

        tf.PrepareDrawString(
            txt,
            font,
            new XRect(0, 0, width, XUnit.FromMillimeter(300F)),
            out lastfitchar, out neededHeight);
        return new XSize(width, neededHeight);
    }
```

Maybe it can help someone.